# How to fix hanging Ubuntu on Windows associated with batch programming

Tags: bash, rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a batch file that contains this:

```
bash -c "shell/rsync_A.sh"
bash -c "shell/rsync_B.sh"
```

Each of the shell scripts look like this:

**rsync_A.sh:**

```
rsync --info=progress2 -rptz --delete -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/[MY_CERT].pem"  [MY_REMOTE_UBUNTU_ON_AWS]:[MY_REMOTE_FOLDER1] [MY_LOCAL_DESTINATION_FOLDER1]
rsync --info=progress2 -rptz --delete -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/[MY_CERT].pem"  [MY_REMOTE_UBUNTU_ON_AWS]:[MY_REMOTE_FOLDER2] [MY_LOCAL_DESTINATION_FOLDER2]
```

**rsync_B.sh:**

```
rsync --info=progress2 -rptz --delete -e "ssh -i /root/.ssh/[MY_CERT].pem"  [MY_REMOTE_UBUNTU_ON_AWS]:[MY_REMOTE_FOLDER3] [MY_LOCAL_DESTINATION_FOLDER3]
```

The problem is that bash always, without fail, hangs when I run the batch file. The first rsync command always seems to run fine, the second always fails (whether inside the same sh file or a different one).

By "hangs" I mean that I see a blinking cursor but no bash prompt and there is no way to get out of it without restarting the entire system (lxssmanager hangs when attempting to restart).

Everything always runs 100% fine when I enter bash and run the shell scripts, but as soon as I get batch involved it breaks.

Comment: If you run it with `bash -cx`, you don't see anything which helps with this issue?

Comment: What is the reason for the extra level of indirection? Why not move the `rsync` calls into the main script?

Comment: The only reason the rsync calls are in their own file is because of the issue at hand. i.e. at present I have to enter bash and run the rsync commands or shell scripts... if the rsync commands where stored in the batch file, as they were originally, and this issue persisted, then I could only run my needed rsyncs by copying and pasting out of the batch script into the bash terminal. As is, I can enter bash and run the shell scripts directly.

Comment: Update: the issue does not present itself when I have an ubuntu window open next to the windows cmd window.

Comment: Update: I was trying to have bash open and close before running my rsync commands as a work around to the last update. Then I decided to try "start ubuntu run 'rsync... '"... that works, but then ubuntu hangs and it wont work a second time. This is crazy town.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why or how... but the solution was to uninstall BitDefender.